# Nesting [ ] with PHP RegExp

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to ensure that a string in PHP has only letters, hyphens or apostraphes. To accomplish this I wanted to make a range of valid characters using  [ ]. So my idea was to do this:

```
[[A-Za-z]-'] // Weird syntax highlighting here
```

Will this work? Is it possible to nest brackets like that? This is meant to match a single character that is either a letter, a hyphen, or an apostraphe. I may be approaching the problem naively and that's OK, I just wanted to know if putting brackets within brackets like this is legal in PHP. Thanks!

Comment: I think you can also benefit from this nice overview of available regex design tools: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had no idea tools like this existed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using this in one of the regular expression matching functions (like `preg_match("[[A-Za-z]-']*", ...)`, and in that case, it's a question not of PHP syntax, but regular expression syntax. And the answer is no, you can't nest brackets like that. If you want a regular expression that matches only a letter, hyphen, or apostrophe, use `[A-Za-z'-]`. (The hyphen goes last so that the regex engine knows that it's not representing a range of characters like `A-Z`. Alternatively you can escape the hyphen with a backslash, then you can put it anywhere: `[A-Za-z\-']`.)

Comment: Ah, perfect. I was making it unnecessarily complicated! Thanks.

Comment: Just escape the hyphen. Always escape the hyphens, so you never forget to. Saves you an hour in a lifetime =)

Comment: @Rudie: good advice, I suppose. I've just gotten used to putting the hyphen at the end whenever I need it in a character class.

Comment: That works just as well. I was learned to always escape it. Just to be safe. In the end it doesn't matter I guess, as long as it works the way you want.

Comment: That’s not a letter.  It’s A-Z.

Comment: @tchrist: In the English language, letters are A-Z and a-z. Clearly the OP is comfortable with this being his accepted character range.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand.

What's wrong with

```
[A-Za-z'-]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

```
[\pL\p{Pd}'ʹ’]⁠ ⁠
```

That matches:

- any *Letter* character⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠ ⁠
- any *Dash Punctuation* character
- U+0027  APOSTROPHE (which is not the preferred form)
- U+02B9  MODIFIER LETTER PRIME
- U+2019  RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that a string contains only the desired characters you can do it two ways:

- You know its good if all chars in the string are valid.
- You know its bad if any one char in the string is invalid.

Here is a PHP snippet that demonstrates both methods:

```php
// Method 1: Good if all chars in the string are valid.
$re_all_valid = '/^[A-Za-z\-\']*$/';
if (preg_match($re_all_valid, $text)) {
    echo("GOOD: String contains all valid characters.\n");
} else {
    echo("BAD: String does NOT contain all valid characters.\n");
}

// Method 2: Bad if any one char in the string is invalid.
$re_one_invalid = '/[^A-Za-z\-\']/';
if (preg_match($re_one_invalid, $text)) {
    echo("BAD: String contains one invalid character.\n");
} else {
    echo("GOOD: String does NOT contain one invalid character.\n");
}
```

Notes: Method 1 requires anchors at both ends of the string and a quantifier applied to the positive character class. Method 2 uses a negated character class and only needs to match one character in the string. Method 2 is likely more efficient.